# Getting keywords from messages

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, gensim, text-classification

My aim here is text summarization, not sure if I'm doing it correctly but here's the plan. I've got a dataframe called train_data. Each cell in every row contains messages. Now, I am looking to iterate over each cell or each message in the dataframe column to get the keywords from each message, using the gensim.summarization.keyword package.

I understand that the keyword function takes text as an input and I can't pass the whole df column inside so tried to iterate each cell over the keyword function as text but it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing here? Here's my code.

```
cols = train_data.new_msg
for col in cols:
    cols

train_data['keywords'] = keywords(col)
```

I then plan to count the length of original vs new message(ie keyword column) to get the compression rate/ratio.

Comment: for calculating length of original message, do you want  unique word count or all word need to taken for calculating length ????

Answer (score 0):

```
train_data['keywords'] = train_data['Name of column which contain text'].apply(lambda x: keywords(x).replace('\n', ', '))
```